# Name for special marginal distribution

Tags: probability, marginal-distribution

Given $P(X_1, \dots, X_N)$ is there a name for the following two marginal distributions?

- The marginal, $P(X_n)$, including only the $n$-th variable
- The marginal, $P(X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}, X_{n+1}, \dots, X_N)$ including all but the $n$-th variable

Comment: I was thinking of using "univariate marginal" for the first and "orthogonal projection" for the second marginal distribution. But maybe there is something more standard or more effective.

Answer (score 0):

The first I would simply call the marginal distribution of $X_n$.

I don't think the second would usually be called a marginal distribution, since the name is generally used only for univariate distributions. It's true that you've marginalized out a variable, but it's still a joint distribution. Perhaps you could call it the "joint distribution excluding $X_n$" or something like that. I don't know of a standard name. I wouldn't recommend "orthogonal projection" since (to me at least) it's unclear what that means.

Comment: Actually according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) a marginal should be any subset of the $N$ variables...